# wpml change category link to translated one

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

I am using Advanced Custom Field and to make a dynamic category link I used

```
<a href="/?cat=<?php the_field('vltu-link'); ?>" ></a>
```

The php code above return category id.

It's working fine. But the problem is when I click on a translated category link, WPML changes it to primary category link.

I.e.: my primary category id is 10 and it's translated one is 11. The link that I made show `/?cate=11` but when I click WPML change it to `/?cate=10`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you. you mean I should add ,123 as you did above?I'll try it.

Comment: I did it and the out put is nothing.